# Wordpress localhost redirect

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I recently moved an WordPress installation from server to my computer. On server it was running on port 80 but on my localhost I use 8080. When I try to access http://localhost:8080/wordpress it redirects me to http://localhost/wordpress.
I found a setting named siteurl in the options table and changed that but it did not do the trick. Anyone know where i can change this setting?

Comment: Did my answer helped you out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was more complexed than I imagined. I went through a lot of "move wordpress site" tutorials until it worked. Guess replacing all the links in database from domain name to localhost/wordpress did the work.

Answer (score 0):

I dont use WordPress, but for what I know about WP is that you have a Config part (web) that you can change that type of settings. So, maybe is the database that you have to search where is that port and change it to 8080, because it is forcing it to use 80.

Here you go with a little search in google: [Solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-port-number)

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to install Wordpress on your local computer then you need to change website-name to your localhost-path before importing sql file. otherwise it will redirect you to your website